# Cost analysis of Thomas algorithm

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matlab

I am doing somework using the Thomas algoritm when is comes to solving tridiagonal matrix. However, I cant find any information regarding the computational cost of the Thomas algorithm (TA). I do know that the computational cost of TA is O(n), but I just dont know how to "prove" it or show it.
My task is to compare TA to gaussian elmination with pivoting.

Is there anyway I can show that the computaional cost of TA is O(n)?

Comment: A simple remark: a tridiagonal matrix has only $3n-2$ nonzero elements and the Thomas algorithm eliminates them the Gaussian way, without creating new nonzero elements.

Comment: Looking at the code makes the $O(n)$ bound obvious. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm

Comment: Have you counted the flops for small values of $n$, say, $n=1,2,3,4$? Is there pattern emerging that you can generalize?

Comment: Were you ultimately able to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can just count operations... Assuming you have a tridiagonal matrix with diagonal $b_1, \cdots, b_n$, sub-diagonal  $a_2, \cdots, a_n$ and super-diagonal $c_1,\cdots, c_{n-1}$, the Thomas algorithm consists in computing $c', d'$ according to
$$
c_1'=c_1/b_1, \quad c_i'=\frac{c_i}{b_i-a_ic_{i-1}'}, \,\, i=2,\cdots, n-1
$$

$$
d_1'=d_1/b_1, \quad d_i'=\frac{d_i-a_id_{i-1}'}{b_i-a_i c_{i+1}'}, \,\, i=2,\cdots, n
$$

and then computing $x$ by back-substitution

$$
x_n = d_n',\quad x_i = d_i'-c_i'x_{i+1}, \,\, i = n-1, \cdots, 1
$$

So, counting operations you have:

- Sums/subtractions: $(n-2) + 2(n-1)+(n-1) = 4n-5$
- Multiplications/divisions: $(1+2(n-2)) + (1 + 3(n-1)) + (n-1) = 6n-6$

So, the total operation count is $10n -11$, clearly $O(n)$, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Your flop count is $-1$ for $n=1$.

Comment: @CarlChristian $n$ cannot be 1. I could have stated it explicitly, but it is implied by the definition of $a$.

Comment: The algorithm as stated applies to the case of $n=1$. There are simply no subdiagonal or superdiagonal elements and most of the assignments are empty. The only operation that is left is the single division $x_1 = d'_1 = d_1/b_1$. Hence, the actual flop count is $1$. Your write $c'_{i+1}$ instead of $c'_{i-1}$. Recycling the value $b_i - a_i c'_{i-1}$ will allow you to safe 2 flops for most rows.

Answer (score 0):

I find it difficult to count flops by scanning the mathematical statement of many algorithms. There is one method that significantly reduces the risk of mistakes.

1. Implement the algorithm and verify that the software returns accurate results.
2. Augment the software to also count the number of flops.
3. Analyze the software manually and formalize a conjecture regarding the flop count.
4. Verify experimentally that the conjecture agrees with the exact flop count.

We must complete Step 1 before we do anything else. Step 2 is straight forward if we examine the source code one line at a time. Once we have implemented the algorithm and examined the arithmetic operations is much simpler to complete Step 3. If we discern that the flop count is a polynomial of degree $k$, then we need no more than $k+1$ experiments to verify that the we have isolated the correct polynomial.

In the case of the Thomas algorithm for solving a tridiagonal linear system of dimension $m$ the exact flop count is $8m-7$.

Below follows a MATLAB implementation of the algorithm that adheres to the principles listed above. Residuals are explicitly calculated in order to catch grievous programming errors and compare against the theoretical expectations. The flop count refers to the flop count for the factorization and solve phases.

The factorization function has a flop count of $3m-3$. We observe that this count is consistent with the case of $m=1$ where the factorization is trivial and does not require any flops.

```
function [L, U, R, rres, flops, diff]=thomasFactor(A)

% Isolate dimension of the problem
m=size(A,1);

% Initialize flop count 
flops=0;

% Create a copy
B=A;

% Main loop has length m-1
for j=1:m-1
    % Compute multiplier
    B(j+1,j)=B(j+1,j)/B(j,j);
    % Update the trailing submatrix;
    B(j+1,j+1)=B(j+1,j+1)-B(j+1,j)*B(j,j+1);
    % Update flops
    flops=flops+3;
end

% Extract L and U
L=eye(m,m)+tril(B,-1); U=triu(B);

% Compute residual
R=A-L*U;

% Compute relative residual
rres=norm(R,'inf')/norm(A,'inf');
    
% Exact count based on analyzing the main loop.
count=3*m-3;

% Difference
diff=count-flops;
```

The solve function has a flop count of $5m-4$. We observe that this count is consistent with the case of $m=1$ where the solve requires a single division.

```
function [x, r, rres, flops, diff]=thomasSolve(A,L,U,b)

% Isolate the dimension of the problem
m=size(L,1);

% Initialize flop count
flops=0;

% Initialize solution
x=b;

% Forward sweep of length m-1
for j=2:m
    % Do the linear update
    x(j)=x(j)-L(j,j-1)*x(j-1);
    % Update flops
    flops=flops+2;
end

% Do the central division
x(m)=x(m)/U(m,m);

% Update flops 
flops=flops+1;

% Backward sweep of length m-1
for j=m-1:-1:1
    % Do the linear update
    x(j)=x(j)-U(j,j+1)*x(j+1);
    % Do the central division
    x(j)=x(j)/U(j,j);
    % Update flops
    flops=flops+3;
end

% Compute residual
r=b-A*x;

% Compute relative residual
rres=norm(r,'inf')/norm(b,'inf');

% Exact count based on analyzing the loops
count=5*m-4;

% Difference 
diff=count-flops;
```

Comment: I understand your point, and recognise the utility of being able to check operation counts. However, I think it should not be presented as a first approach. Imagine you are deciding between 10 algorithms... Do you think it is a reasonable approach to implement them all before you make your decision?

Comment: @PierreCarre: When I have to decide between algorithms, I use of state-of-the-art implementations of the old algorithms and implement the new algorithms myself. I have never had to choose between 10 new algorithms. What did I write that made you think that my advice is meant for this case?

Comment: I am just arguing that in most cases there is no need to implement an algorithm to conclude something about its computational complexity and I would not encourage this as a first approach.

Comment: @PierreCarre I have found that I do not understand an algorithm until I have implemented it several times in different languages. You are not in strong position to argue against my answer. You are currently analyzing the wrong algorithm because you made a typo when you stated the algorithm. Had you implemented your algorithm in MATLAB, then you would have found the error when you verified the result. Had you done it in C, then you would have caught the error when valgrind reported an out of bounds memory access. You need to divide with the *same* number when you compute $c_i'$ and $d_i'$.